# Seaborn module - histplot - trying to plot histogram with correct data

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, seaborn, data-visualization

Could someone please help me solve this?

I am trying to plot an histogram where the Y axis is in percentage and the X axis ranges between 0 (extremely unlikely) to 10 (extremely likely).

```
import seaborn as sns

sns.set(rc = {'figure.figsize':(8,6)})
sns.set_theme(style="whitegrid")

col = "4.1. Extremely Unlikely vs Extremely Likely"
data = file[[col,"1. Vaccination Status"]].dropna()
data[col] = data[col].astype(int)

hist = sns.histplot(data=data, x=col, hue="1. Vaccination Status", multiple="dodge", stat='count')
hist.set_title("Likeliness to recive vaccination")
hist.set_xlabel('0:Extremely Unlikely, 10:Extremely Likely')
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1A0UY.png)

```
data[col]

48     1
27     0
2      5
36    10
12     9
Name: 4.1. Extremely Unlikely vs Extremely Likely, dtype: int32
```

Comment: What is your question?  Did you try `stat='percent'`? Note that as your data is discrete, it would help to add that information to `sns.histplot(...., discrete=True)`. Otherwise, the histogram could look quite messy.  You can also try `sns.countplot(...)`.

Comment: Thank you! It works now with stat='percent' and discrete=True.
Do you know how I can make the x-axis display all the values? 
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] <-- x-axis

Comment: `ax = hist` and `ax.set_xticks(range(11))`